# Multiple Django Celery Tasks are trying to save to the same object and failing

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have three Celery @tasks in my tasks.py file that are often queued and processed simultaneously by separate workers with similar processing times for each.  The problem that I believe I am running into is that they are all trying to update the same user profile object before the other ones are complete.  It appears that the last of the three processes to finish is the one that successfully writes to the database. If I run these with a few seconds in between the tasks all finish fine.

Any idea what is the problem or what is a way to keep trying to save to the profile until it actually works?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Even if these are separate fields being updated by each process?  Is there a way to synchronously string tasks with the same userprofile row together?

Comment: Would there be a way to do a try: except: logic around the profile save?

Comment: And if you want to know more Wikipedia has pretty decent articles about ACID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID and Isolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django ORM can play a trick here. If you use `model_object.save()` method, it updates all the fields. If your tasks are updating different fields in the same object, you may consider using `ModelClass.objects.filter(pk=model_id).update(some_field=some_value)`, but here you may fall into how different RDBMS implement table/row locking.

Another option is to use [Celery Chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) and update user profile on completion of all tasks fetching user data. You may need to implement a distributed semaphore, so the only chord task will be executing for the same user profile at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using django because you tagged it as such. If so, you can use select_for_update ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)) to lock the objects. This will block the other workers until the transaction completes. If your tasks run a long time you could get timeouts so catch that exception and retry if necessary.

```
from django.db import transaction
from celery.task import task

@task
def mytask(mpk):
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        my_obj = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=mpk)
        ...
```

Note that this won't work with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's more a database lock issue. Have you tried to edit your configuration file and allow more concurrencies on your database ? For instance on Postgre Debian to edit your conf file :

```
nano /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Then you could set something like this in the conf file :

```
max_connections=100
shared_buffers = 3000MB
temp_buffers = 800MB
effective_io_concurrency = 5
max_worker_processes = 15
```

This should allow you to read/write as you are discribing.